# How to use bitmap from url as icon for ItemizedOverlay - WITH CACHE?

Tags: android, android-mapview

I've seen plenty of examples of how to create an ItemizedOverlay on MapView with an image from the bundle.  I've seen plenty of examples of how to get a Drawable from a URL.  I've even managed to cobble the two together to use a drawable made from a bitmap fetched remotely.  Now the problem I'm running into is how can I make that Drawable cachable?

Answer (score 0):

Don't cache drawables - this can lead to [memory leak](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html).

You should cache Bitmaps and create Drawables from then when needed.